# prevent CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent already pressed modifier keys

Tags: cocoa, events

I'm using `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` to create and `CGEventPost` to post an event on the Mac. The following code works perfectly for pressing the 'a' key.

```
CGEventRef downEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 0, YES);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, downEvent);
CFRelease(downEvent);
```

The problem lies in the fact that the user might have a modifier key pressed. For example when the user already has the Command key pressed while my keyboard events are send, Command + a will be sent to the active application in stead of just the character a.

Is there a way to work around this? Can I explicitly say that I want to post a character, ignoring any (modifier) keys that might have already been pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try setting the event's flags to `0`?

Comment: Nope haven't tried that, figured it would not help because the modifier keys are set by a previous event.

Worth a try though.

Edit:
Worked, thanks!